# Show table/form based on selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, selection

I know there's questions like this in here, but I couldn't find an answer that would work for me.

What I want is to show form "default" is certain options are selected (In this case everything but "Ban Appeal" or "Ban Appeal (Spanish)", and I want form "unban" to be displayed only if Ban Appeal, or Ban Appeal (Spanish) is selected the shortest and easiest way possible.

I know it's possible with JQuery or Javascript

Here's my code:

```
<select>
    <option value="Ban Appeal" selected="selected"><-- Choose Topic --></option>
    <option value="Ban Appeal">Ban Appeal</option>
    <option value="Ban Appeal (Spanish)">Ban Appeal (Spanish)</option>
    <option value="Bug Report">Bug Report</option>
    <option value="Hacker Report">Hacker Report</option>
    <option value="Staff Application">Staff Application</option>
    <option value="Staff Complaint">Staff Complaint</option>
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
    <option value="Suggestion">Suggestion</option>
</select>

<form name="default" id="default" style="display:none"> <!-- Template for every option but Unban/Spanish Unban -->
<table>
<!-- Leaving out everything in here because it's a lot -->
</table>
</form>

<form name="unban" id="unban" style="display:none"> <!-- Template for unban/Spanish unban -->
<table>
    <tr>
    <!-- Leaving out everything in here because it's a lot. -->
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you can add a function when the select is changed. Then, check which value it has and show or hide the forms accordingly, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){             // you probably have a document-ready function already
    $('select').change(function(){        // onchange event
        switch ($(this).val()) {          // check the value
            case 'no-select':
                $('form').hide();
                break;
            case 'Ban Appeal':
            case 'Ban Appeal (Spanish)': 
                $('form#unban').show();
                $('form#default').hide();
                break;
            default:
                $('form#default').show();
                $('form#unban').hide();
        }
    }).trigger('change');                 // trigger the change event to make it work
                                          // directly when the DOM is loaded
});
```

You should consider giving the `select` an id as well and use it in the JavaScript; otherwise extra selects in the other forms will cause problems.

I hope it's clear how to extend this little snippet if later you want to add more forms or options.

Comment: Thank you - I changed select to #topic (Select id/name), but when the page loads it instantly shows the Ban Appeal form, even though it's selected on "<-- Choose Topic -->", while I'd want nothing to show up if there's no topic selected

Comment: @Prophettt that's because the 'choose topic' option has _value_ 'Ban Appeal'. Change it to 'no-select' or something like that, and add a case for that in the switch in the JavaScript.

Comment: Didn't realize - But thank you for updated your reply and telling me! It works perfectly now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just a little shorter even previous answer works as expected:

```
$(function(){
    $('select').on('change', function(){
        var indexAppeal = !this.value.indexOf('Ban Appeal');
        $('#default').toggle(indexAppeal);
        $('#unban').toggle(!indexAppeal);
    }).change();
});
```